# why does groupby function returns duplicated data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am testing pandas.groupby function and have generated a random dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,size=(6,3)), columns=list('abc'))`

in a random case df is:

```
   a  b  c
0  2  2  2
1  1  4  2
2  3  0  1
3  2  1  3
4  0  2  2
5  2  1  4
```

when I use the following code to print out the groupby object, I get some interesting results.

```
def func(x):
    print(x)
df.groupby("a").apply(lambda x: func(x))

   a  b  c
0  0  1  4
   a  b  c
0  0  1  4
   a  b  c
2  2  4  1
3  2  2  1
   a  b  c
1  4  0  0
4  4  4  3
```

Could anybody let me know why index 0 appear twice in this case?

Comment: To avoid this behavior, and also to prevent having an output of `None`, you can also just iterate over the groups `for idx,grp in df.groupby('a'): print(grp)`

Comment: Yes, that could work. I just have a very big table and I think .apply iterates faster than a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataFrame.groupby.apply` evaluates the first group twice to determine whether a *fast path for calculation* can be followed for the remaining groups.  This behavior has changed in recent versions of `pandas` as discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/24748)

Comment: Interesting... Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @Y.Peng you're welcome; please mark this as the *accepted answer* if you feel this answers your question